# Share extension with NSExtensionJavaScriptPreprocessingFile no image

Tags: ios, swift, ios8-share-extension, share-extension

I'm building an iOS Share extension. I need to grab some data from web pages so I'm using a JavaScript file to grab that data and send it back to the app to be used in the extension.

I noticed the following. When I set the `NSExtensionJavaScriptPreprocessingFile` key with my JavaScript file the `SLComposeServiceViewController` is showing up perfect but without image!

Like this:

[image]

If I remove the `NSExtensionJavaScriptPreprocessingFile` my `SLComposeServiceViewController` shows up like this:

[image]

But I need to access to some data from the Webpage (the one I grab with JS) but I also need that image! I'm completely lost how to get both or I don't even know if that's possible because Apple docs are kind of confusing.

Thanks!

Comment: Same struggle here. What did you end up finding out?

Comment: After many hours of testing, I believe that you have to choose one or the other. You cannot have both the previewImage from the webpage, and use NSExtensionJavaScriptPreprocessingFile. Not the answer I had hoped to find.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the answer to this for sure, but I've been looking at questions about share extension myself and came across a couple that might be useful to you.  The general idea is to continue using your JavaScript preprocessor and manually set the preview image.

Retrieve the image with something like:

```
[itemProvider loadPreviewImageWithOptions:nil completionHandler:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error){

   if(image){
        //do anything here with the image
   }

}
```

as described here:
[iOS 8 Share Extension Safari Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26426524/ios-8-share-extension-safari-image?rq=1#34605632)

And set the preview image of `SLComposeServiceViewController` by overriding `loadPreviewView`:

```
override func loadPreviewView() -> UIView! {        
  imagePreviewView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "imageName"))
  return imagePreviewView
}
```

as described here:
[Change the preview image in an SLComposeServiceViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35323721/change-the-preview-image-in-an-slcomposeserviceviewcontroller?rq=1)

Again, I don't know if this will work.  Just seems like it should from what I've read.

Comment: No, I don't think this works. The same problem stated by the OP still stands.

Comment: I tested this and it doesn't work. There is no image coming through - it makes me wonder if Apple has a default javascript processor that provides the image & when you add your own processor you overwrite theirs.